# I need helping dismissing modal on submit. I am using angularJs for databinding, and Jquery and bootstrap (but not ui-bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, api

Button to launch modal:

```
<button data-hover="tooltip" title="Edit" style="height:25px; width:35px" class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".eCategory-modal-sm" ng-click="budget.getCategory(category.Id)"></button>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div>
    <div class="">
        <br />
        <div class="modal fade eCategory-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Edit Budget </h4><small>Delete Previous Information and Enter New </small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" ng-submit="budget.editCategory()">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="budget.cmodel.Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Expense/Income</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="budget.cmodel.ExpenseTF" ng-options="o.v as o.n for o in [{n: 'Income', v: false}, {n: 'Expense', v: true}]"></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="this.form.reset()">Close</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 c.editCategory = function () {
    return $http.post(serviceBase + '/api/Category/Edit', c.cmodel).then(function (response) {
        c.cmodel = response.data;
        return response;
    });
};
```

ALSO, I have looked at many examples of this type of question. Most of the answers have things for directives. My application does not have anything happening in directives. I am only using angular controllers, services(for security), and templates for loading the views. I am new to this so I'm not sure how the data flow of the application is working so far. However, I do know that if i inject things into the application, my security breaks... this is due to tokens being lost. So please dont give me a solution that involves me having to inject into my applications. PS. I have tried injecting Ui-Bootstrap and using their modals.... but the it does not work different solution if you have one. If you give me code to paste please tell me where to make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>How does the close button dismiss the modal? 

Answer:</strike>

```
    data-dismiss="modal"
```

Solution to your problem:

```
    <button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

Well poo... have you tried putting $('.modal').modal('hide'); in your javascript function?

```
c.editCategory = function () {
    return $http.post(serviceBase + '/api/Category/Edit', c.cmodel).then(function (response) {
        c.cmodel = response.data;
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
        return response;
    });
};
```

Comment: This does not work, because if i dismiss modal on the submit, the form is not sent. meaning the user input does not get changed/added to database.

Comment: the hide modal does not work either. :\. is there a way to maybe just refresh the state or something on submit? like it submits...then it would just refresh the current page?